# I have a string role = "test1,test2" I need to replace the "," with a " "," " so the final output should be like this role = "test1","test2"

Tags: python, python-3.x

repalce a string with python

I have tried the replace function but it gives me an str error

Comment: Do share your sample code it might help others to understand your thought process and guide various approaches with detailed input/output expected.

Comment: And please also edit your question: The title is for a succinct summary, not the question itself. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

```
a="test1,test2"
a="\""+a.replace(",","\",\"")+"\""
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer to what you asked.

```py
old_string = "test1,test2"
new_string = old_string.replace(',', '","')
# new_string = 'test1","test2'
```

When you want to use `"` in a string, you can use the single quote for the string.

However are you sure you are not looking for the `split` functionality.